# Normalization of Term-frequency and Inverse Document Frequency of varying documents lengths to calculate cosine similarity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I have been trying to find thousands of textual document's similarity against one single query. And every document size is majorly varying (from 20 words to 2000 words)

I did refer the question: [tf-idf documents of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704220/tf-idf-documents-of-different-length)

But that doesn't help me because a fraction of cosine value matters too when comparing with a pool of documents to maintain order.

I then came across a wonderful normalization blog: [Tf-Idf and Cosine similarity](https://janav.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity/). But the problem here is to tweak in the TermFreq of every document.

I am using `sklearn` to calculate tf-idf. But now I am looking for some utility similar to sklearn's tf-idf performance. An iterative approach over all the documents to calculate TF and then modify it is not only time consuming but also not efficient.

Any knowledge/suggestions are appreciated.